# Supervisord configuration for Laravel

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, supervisord

I am using Supervisord to help keep my Laravel-based App queue running. And I am wondering if the below  configuration is correct.

In Laravel docs, for example, `numprocs` is set 8, which means that Supervisord will run queue:work 8 times, is and why this is a good thing?

Also, should I be using --daemon in the queue:work command?

```sh
[program:app-queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/app/public_html/app/artisan queue:work --daemon --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
startsecs=0
stopwaitsecs=60
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/app/public_html/app/storage/logs/queue-out.log
```

Comment: RE: `--daemon`, [the docs say](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html): "*Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves. Instead, they should run in the foreground. They should not detach from the terminal from which they are started.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numprocs` will spawn 8 processes that will then poll the queue every 3 seconds. When `daemon` is set, these processes will not restart unless told to which has both advantages in terms of server load and disadvantages in the form of some potential edge cases when updating your code base.

Having 8 processes means that you have potentially 8 times the throughput when running jobs.

---

**Example:**

There are many scenarios where having multiple processes running in parallel are advantageous.

For instance, say you are processing 1000 users and want to check how many comments each has made in the last month. Say each check takes a minute to process (extreme but it makes a better point), it would take 1000 minutes to complete if you run then in sequence by looping through a array or collection of a 1000 users. That's over 16 hours!

If you queued these as jobs and have `numprocs` set to 16, then you are done in just over and hour!

Comment: So, as I understand, not using --daemon would increase server load, right? I may use it but I need to `queue:restart` every time the code changes.

Comment: As for the `numprocs`. "Having 8 processes means that you have potentially 8 times the throughput when running jobs." I still don't really understand if and why this is a good thing (or not)!

Is't one process is enough to handle the queued jobs one by one, why create 8 times of this?!

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of parallel processing which shoulde help. As for `daemonizing`, it does have big advantages but it's been a while since i've tried it. I had some bad experiences with it back in Laravel 5.1 and I haven't tried since!